# Do native English speakers understand the word "onsen"

Tags: meaning, loanwords

I live in Japan, and all native English speakers can understand the word "onsen". It means hot spring and comes from the Japanese language.

I wonder if native English speakers living in US, UK, or other countries can understand it?

Comment: I don't know the word, and I'm sure only those few British people with special knowledge of Japan would be likely to know it.

Comment: I knew it was a Japanese word, but I would have had to look up the meaning unless it was clear from the context.

Comment: I knew it, with a rough understanding of the meaning. I'm British and while I've been to Japan on business that's not (directly) how I would have heard the word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wonder if native English speakers living in US, UK, or other countries can understand [onsen]?

You should assume that they don't. General knowledge about hot springs in Japan is usually limited to the monkeys that seem to spend a lot of time in them in winter. In such reports, the hot springs are always referred to as "hot springs".

> In Japan... all native English speakers can understand the word "onsen".

This is not a relevant observation. All foreigners pick up the odd word in the language of the country in which they live.

Answer (score 2):

Personally speaking, although I'm familiar with Japanese culture generally, the term 'onsen' was new to me.

As at the date of this posting, 'onsen' is not listed in the [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=onsen), nor is it listed on the Etymonline website.

It is listed on Wordnik, but the only entry they reference is from [Wiktionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/onsen):

> onsen (noun): A hot spring in Japan, often with accompanying bathing
> facilities.
>
> From Japanese 温泉 (おんせん, onsen).

On running an [ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=onsen&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Consen%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Consen%3B%2Cc0), the word seems to have gradually come into use in English in print through the last quarter of the 20th Century, mainly through references to Japan.

Comment: Comparing the Ngram for **onsen,privy,pestilential**, you will see "onsen" has very few hits. It remains very rare https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=onsen%2Cprivy%2Cpestilential&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3. I also note that "onsen" is usually either accompanied by an English explanation, or is in the work of a Japanese author.